# How to change to unicode utf-8 in LyX

Tags: lyx, unicode

I have an error In LyX, the error is in Hebrew language, it says that I need to change the unicode to utf-8, how can I do that in LyX?

Edit, this is the error:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Have you had a look at https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Unicode ? What specific problem did you encounter?

Comment: What is your LyX version and what is the exact error message?

Comment: Added the error

Comment: This seems to be an error about the file name itself, rather than the contents.  Try giving a name with ascii characters instead.

Comment: I changed the file name, and still doesn't work, it gives me error to change the unicode to utf8

Comment: this happens while I'm trying to compile via xetex

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but maybe go to Document > Settings and in the search (upper-left) type "encoding". Otherwise, please provide a minimal example.